# maven project showing error element reportPlugins is not allowed here

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, appium

today, i make a new maven project and added dependencies. i am completely new to this. everything successfully happens but at the end when i build my project its showing some project errors. i am trying to edit this file but its only readable even i can't find out its path. i try to reinstall all dependencies but not much has changed.

`Element reportPlugins is not allowed here Cannot resolve symbol 'reportPlugin' Cannot resolve symbol 'groupId' Cannot resolve symbol 'groupId' Cannot resolve symbol 'artifactId' Cannot resolve symbol 'artifactId' Cannot resolve symbol 'reportPlugin' Element reportPlugins is not allowed here`

my effective-pom.xml

````
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Pi_automator</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>7.5.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-alpha-7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <directory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\target</directory>
    <finalName>Pi_automator-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\riyaz\IdeaProjects\Pi_automator\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>```
````

Comment: First question: Is the posted pom your real pom file?

Answer (score 1):

This warning is produced by Maven 3.5+ as the configuration in your pom file is indeed not recommended. Please use normal `reporting` configuration as it is not recommended to use `reportPlugins`.

See related Maven issue: *[MNG-6189](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6189) WARN if maven-site-plugin configuration contains reportPlugins element*